# chart does not show (only text shows up) for dynamic added svg in nvd3 / d3

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

I'm trying to add a piechart for a `svg` element in nvd3

It works when the element is in html, but not when it's added in jquery.

Compare [working](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/pu2jfpvq/1/)
and [not working](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/pu2jfpvq/3/)

it seems to be a css conflict per [this bug](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/605).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the problem can be solved by using D3 to insert the SVG instead of jQuery. Essentially D3 can do most of the things that jQuery does so there's no point using it.

Replace your jQuery code with:

```
d3.select('#container').append('svg').attr('id', 'svg2');
```